# Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: arduino-nano, ir, rgb-led, code-review

Basically what i am trying to do is use an ir remote to turn an rgb on/off and have a few preset colors as well as being able to increase/decrease red/green/blue independently. I don't know much about C/C++ so this is really hard to troubleshoot.

```c++
#include <IRremote.h>

int rbright;
int gbright;
int bbright;
int before;
int RECV_PIN=12; //data out of IR receiver connects to pin 12
int redPin=11;
int greenPin=10;
int bluePin=9;
int steps=5;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

//uncomment this line if using a Common Anode LED
#define COMMON_ANODE

void setup()
{
    before=0;
    rbright=80;
    gbright=0;
    bbright=80;
    irrecv.enableIRIn(); // start the receiver
    pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(bluePin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
        if (results.value==B54A3AC5){ //Code to turn the LED ON/OFF
            if(before==0){ // if the LED was turned off, then we turn it on
                digitalWrite(redpin,HIGH);
                digitalWrite(greenpin,HIGH);
                digitalWrite(bluepin,HIGH);
                before=1; //LED is now turned on
            }
            else{
                digitalWrite(redpin,LOW);
                digitalWrite(greenpin,LOW);
                digitalWrite(bluepin,LOW); //if the LED was turned on, then we turn it off
                before=0;
            }
        }
        if (results.value==B54A8A75 && before==1){ //Code to decrease the red
            if(rbright-255/steps<0){
                analogWrite(redpin,rbright);
            }
            else{
                rbright=rbright-255/steps;
                analogWrite(redpin,rbright);
            }
        }
        if (results.value==B54A7A85 && before==1){ //Code to increase the red
            if(rbright+255/steps>255){
                analogWrite(redpin,rbright);
            }
            else{
                rbright=rbright+255/steps;
                analogWrite(redpin,rbright);
            }
        }
        if (results.value==B54AB24D && before==1){ //Code to decrease the green
            if(gbright-255/steps<0){
                analogWrite(greenpin,gbright);
            }
            else{
                gbright=gbright-255/steps;
                analogWrite(greenpin,gbright);
            }
        }
        if (results.value==B54A32CD && before==1){ //Code to increase the green
            if(gbright+255/steps>255){
                analogWrite(greenpin,gbright);
            }
            else{
                gbright=gbright+255/steps;
                analogWrite(greenpin,gbright);
            }
        }
        if (results.value==B54A0AF5 && before==1){ //Code to decrease the blue
            if(bbright-255/steps<0){
                analogWrite(bluepin,bbright);
            }
            else{
                bbright=bbright-255/steps;
                analogWrite(bluepin,bbright);
            }
        }
        if (results.value==B54ACA35 && before==1){ //Code to increase the blue
            if(bbright+255/steps>255){
                analogWrite(bluepin,bbright);
            }
            else{
                bbright=bbright+255/steps;
                analogWrite(bluepin,bbright);
            }
        }
        if (results.value==B54AA956 && before==1){ //Code yellow
            setColor(255, 255, 0);
        }
        if (results.value==B54A2AD5 && before==1){ //Code purple
            setColor(80, 0, 80);
        }
        if (results.value==B54AEA15 && before==1){ //Code aqua
            setColor(0, 255, 255);
        }
        irrecv.resume();
    }

void setColor(int red, int green, int blue)
{
#ifdef COMMON_ANODE
    red = 255 - red;
    green = 255 - green;
    blue = 255 - blue;
#endif
    analogWrite(redPin, red);
    analogWrite(greenPin, green);
    analogWrite(bluePin, blue);
}
```

The errors i get are

> rgbcontrolir_ino.ino: In function ‘void loop()’:
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:35:24: error: ‘B54A3AC5’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:37:20: error: ‘redpin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:38:20: error: ‘greenpin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:39:20: error: ‘bluepin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:43:20: error: ‘redpin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:44:20: error: ‘greenpin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:45:20: error: ‘bluepin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:48:22: error: ‘B54A8A75’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:50:19: error: ‘redpin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:54:17: error: ‘redpin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:56:22: error: ‘B54A7A85’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:58:19: error: ‘redpin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:62:17: error: ‘redpin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:64:22: error: ‘B54AB24D’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:66:19: error: ‘greenpin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:70:17: error: ‘greenpin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:72:22: error: ‘B54A32CD’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:74:19: error: ‘greenpin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:78:17: error: ‘greenpin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:80:22: error: ‘B54A0AF5’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:82:19: error: ‘bluepin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:86:17: error: ‘bluepin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:88:22: error: ‘B54ACA35’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:90:19: error: ‘bluepin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:94:17: error: ‘bluepin’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:96:22: error: ‘B54AA956’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:100:24: error: ‘B54A2AD5’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:104:24: error: ‘B54AEA15’ was not declared in this scope
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:112:5: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
>   rgbcontrolir_ino.ino:121:5: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input

Comment: > The errors i get are it tells you that those macros are undefined. you need to figure out what they are first before you can fix the errors.

Comment: redpin bluepin etc where defined in the beginning right? Or did i miss something.and the other alpha numeric codes refer to the ir codes from the remote i will use.

Comment: I used the arduino rgb tutorial and the tutorial from great scott on youtube. he used ir library to control led strips with varying brightness. I downloaded the ir libraries and used the irrecvdemo sketch to find the codes on the remote i plan to use

Comment: i feel like it has something to do with the brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors are self-explanatory. You just have to read them carefully.

> ‘B54A3AC5’ was not declared in this scope

The compiler doesn't know what "B54A3AC5" means. Nor do I, but I *gess*
you may mean an hexadecimal 32-bit value. If that's the case, write it
with the prefix "0x", as in `0xb54a3ac5`.

> ‘redpin’ was not declared in this scope

Same thing, it doesn't know what "redpin" is. Oh, wait, you have
declared a variable named `redPin`. Maybe that is what you meant:
"redPin", with an uppercase "P".

> a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token

You tried to define `setColor()` *within* the `loop()` function. You
cannot define a function within a function in C++ (well, you can have
lambdas, but that's irrelevant to your problem).

Had you tried to indent your code properly (like I did in my edit), the
error would have been obvious: there is no closing brace to match the
opening one at the start of `loop()`.

> expected ‘}’ at end of input

Another symptom of the problem above.

---

**Edit**: After reading your code, I have a few suggestions for making
it clearer are more efficient:

1. Declare all the constants with the `const` keyword, at the beginning
   of your program. A common convention is to write them in all caps
   with underscores, to distinguish them from variables.
2. Avoid "magic numbers" within your code (e.g. the IR codes), and use
   properly named constants instead.
3. `before` is hard to understand, give it a name that makes sense. I
   suggest `leds_are_on`. And make it a `bool`, because it can only be
   either `true` or `false`.
4. One way to avoid deeply nested loops is to use `return` statements to
   get out of `loop()` as soon as you know you have nothing to do.

With these suggestions, I would start the program like this:

```c++
#include <IRremote.h>

// Pinout.
const int RECV_PIN  = 12;  // data out of IR receiver
const int RED_PIN   = 11;
const int GREEN_PIN = 10;
const int BLUE_PIN  = 9;

// Number of steps between black and full brightness.
const int STEPS     = 5;

// IR codes.
const uint32_t CODE_ON_OFF     = 0xb54a3ac5;
const uint32_t CODE_LESS_RED   = 0xb54a8a75;
const uint32_t CODE_MORE_RED   = 0xb54a7a85;
const uint32_t CODE_LESS_GREEN = 0xb54ab24d;
const uint32_t CODE_MORE_GREEN = 0xb54a32cd;
const uint32_t CODE_LESS_BLUE  = 0xb54a0af5;
const uint32_t CODE_MORE_BLUE  = 0xb54aca35;
const uint32_t CODE_YELLOW     = 0xb54aa956;
const uint32_t CODE_PURPLE     = 0xb54a2ad5;
const uint32_t CODE_AQUA       = 0xb54aea15;

bool leds_are_on;
int r_bright;
int g_bright;
int b_bright;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
```

and the `loop()` would be like this:

```c++
void loop()
{
    decode_results results;
    if (!irrecv.decode(&results))
        return;

    // If the LEDs are OFF, the only valid action is to turn them
    // ON.
    if (!leds_are_on) {
        if (results.value == CODE_ON_OFF) {
            digitalWrite(RED_PIN,   HIGH);
            digitalWrite(GREEN_PIN, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(BLUE_PIN,  HIGH);
            leds_are_on = true;
        }
        irrecv.resume();
        return;
    }

    // The LEDs are ON: all codes are valid.
    switch (results.value) {
        case CODE_ON_OFF:  // turn OFF
            digitalWrite(RED_PIN,   LOW);
            digitalWrite(GREEN_PIN, LOW);
            digitalWrite(BLUE_PIN,  LOW);
            leds_are_on = false;
            break;
        case CODE_LESS_RED:
            r_bright = constrain(r_bright - 255/steps, 0, 255);
            analogWrite(RED_PIN, r_bright);
            break;
        case CODE_MORE_RED:
            r_bright = constrain(r_bright + 255/steps, 0, 255);
            analogWrite(RED_PIN, r_bright);
            break;
        // etc...
    }
    irrecv.resume();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try some editing and see what I can come up with. the Arduino ide isn't very friendly for writing code. The only code writing exp i have is with BASH scripting. Usually I use a text editor and save the file with the correct prefix and that helps.

Comment: Thanks again! This is a lot of help. After reading your first answer i got the code to compile without errors however the code didnt work as expected. it only turned on/off with full brightness not the purple i was expecting. Is there a good site that will define things for me? specifically I don't know what "case" does

Comment: @KeithBybee: Any book on C or C++ will tell you about switch/case/break.

Comment: After changing over to the formats you suggested I am getting the following error during compilation. "core.a(main.cpp.o): In function `main':
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `setup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
"

Comment: @KeithBybee: That means that you forgot to write `setup()`.

Comment: Well i guess that was obvious. So now i have to versions of this sketch. The one i originally wrote with the errors kinked out and of with case/break instead of if statements. The new one doesnt respond to any buttons being pressed and the old one woth the if statements works until i use any red and then it "freezes". If use the preset purple or the increase/decrease it just stops responding. Other than than it seems think think its on when its off. It will only let me turn individual colors if its off first. I tried putting digital write low for each color in the setup but that did not help

Comment: @KeithBybee: I think I had a logic error within the `if (!leds_are_on) {}` block. Should work better now.

Answer (score 0):

1) You are missing the braces for void loop()

2) Oops !! You have to double check - red**p**in and red**P**in etc. Case sensitive !